# Validar si la sumatoria de todos los datos de una tabla coincide con la de otra tabla relacionados por ciertos campos

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo 2 tablas las cuales presentan la siguiente estructura:

TABLA_1

| Fecha | Sucursal | Operacion | Pedido | Monto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/25/2020 | 445 | 230 | 0 | 0.18 |
| 07/06/2020 | 445 | 230 | 0 | 2 |

TABLA_2

| Fecha | SDest | Concepto | Pedido1 | Monto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/06/2020 | 445 | 230 | 0 | 1.9 |
| 07/06/2020 | 445 | 230 | 0 | 0.1 |
| 07/25/2020 | 445 | 230 | 230023000010003 | 0.17 |

La problematica:

Necesito validar los registros cuya sumatoria del campo monto de la tabla_1 no coincida con el de la tabla_2 para una misma fecha, sucursal, (operación o pedido).

Ejemplo

| Fecha | Sucursal | Operacion | MontoTabla1 | MontoTabla2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/06/2020 | 445 | 230 | 2 | 1.9 |
| 07/06/2020 | 445 | 230 | 2 | 0.1 |
| 07/25/2020 | 445 | 230 | 0.18 | 0.17 |

Al sumar los montos de la tabla 2 coincide con el unico registro de la tabla 1 (2 = 1.9 + 0.1) para el '07/06/2020'.

Al validar para el dia '07/20/2020' estos montos no coinciden por ende debo sacarlos en la consulta.

De momento estoy utilizando CTE para obtener los registros de cada tabla y luego utilizar JOINS

```
WITH Q1 AS (
    SELECT
        Fecha,
        Sucursal,
        Operacion,
        Pedido,
        Monto
    FROM TABLA_1
),
     Q2 AS (
         SELECT
             Fecha,
             SDest,
             Concepto,
             Pedido,
             Monto
         FROM TABLA_2
     ),
     Q3 AS (
         SELECT
             Q1.Fecha AS Fecha,
             Q1.Monto    AS MontoTabla1,
             Q2.Monto    AS MontoTabla2,
             Q1.Sucursal,
             Q1.Operacion,
             Q2.Conceptop
         FROM Q1
         INNER JOIN Q2
             ON Q1.Fecha = Q2.Fecha AND Q1.Sucursal = Q2.SDest AND
                (Q1.Operacion = Q2.Concepto OR Q1.Pedido = Q2.Pedido)
     )
SELECT
    *
FROM Q3
```

Esta consulta me trae como resultado la tabla que coloque un poco mas arriba. La idea no es agrupar dichos registros ya que necesito mostrar aquello que no coinciden

| Fecha | Sucursal | Operacion | MontoTabla1 | MontoTabla2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/25/2020 | 445 | 230 | 0.18 | 0.17 |

Answer (score 0):

A priori aunque el que esperas no es muy claro, esto te puede dar al menos un camino.

**Escenario:**

```
Create table tabla_1
             (
             Fecha     date
           , Sucursal  int
           , Operacion int
           , Pedido    bigint
           , Monto     decimal(5, 2)
             );

Create table tabla_2
             (
             Fecha    date
           , SDest    int
           , Concepto int
           , Pedido1  bigint
           , Monto    decimal(5, 2)
             );
Insert into tabla_1 (Fecha, Sucursal, Operacion, Pedido, Monto)
values
('20200725',445, 230, 0, 0.18),
('20200706',445, 230, 0, 2);
Insert into tabla_2 (Fecha, SDest, Concepto, Pedido1, Monto)
values
('20200706', 445, 230, 0, 1.9),
('20200706', 445, 230, 0, 0.1),
('20200725', 445, 230, 230023000010003, 0.17);
```

Si usamos ctes, para obtener los datos y quieres el monto por fecha, sucursal, operacion y pedido, deberías de usar sum para agrupar los diferentes valores en función, de que el resto de columnas se repitan.

Luego con la salida escoger los resultados es muy simple.

```
With t1 as(
    Select sum(monto) as monto, fecha, sucursal, Operacion, pedido 
    from tabla_1
    group by fecha, sucursal, Operacion, pedido
), t2 as (
    Select sum(monto) as monto, fecha, SDest, Concepto, pedido1
    from tabla_2
    group by fecha, SDest, Concepto, pedido1
)
Select * from t1 full join t2 on t1.Fecha = t2.fecha
        and t1.Sucursal = t2.SDest
        and t1.Operacion = t2.Concepto
        And t1.Pedido = t2.Pedido1;
```

Al hacer un full join tenemos todas las filas, por tanto las de t1 que no tienen t2 y las de t2 que no tienen t1.

Esto se ve mejor en una imagen.

[image: Res]

Si quieres eliminar la fila 1, porque coinciden, tan solo tienes que aplicar un criterio a la misma.

```
With t1 as(
    Select sum(monto) as monto, fecha, sucursal, Operacion, pedido 
    from tabla_1
    group by fecha, sucursal, Operacion, pedido
), t2 as (
    Select sum(monto) as monto, fecha, SDest, Concepto, pedido1
    from tabla_2
    group by fecha, SDest, Concepto, pedido1
)
Select * from t1 full join t2 on t1.Fecha = t2.fecha
        and t1.Sucursal = t2.SDest
        and t1.Operacion = t2.Concepto
        And t1.Pedido = t2.Pedido1
Where 
       t1.monto is null and t2.monto is not null 
    or t1.monto is not null and t2.monto is null  
    or t1.monto<> t2.monto ;
```

[image: Res]

Si los quieres con datos tal cual has expuesto, solo tienes que usar coalesce.

```
With t1 as(
    Select sum(monto) as monto, fecha, sucursal, Operacion, pedido 
    from tabla_1
    group by fecha, sucursal, Operacion, pedido
), t2 as (
    Select sum(monto) as monto, fecha, SDest, Concepto, pedido1
    from tabla_2
    group by fecha, SDest, Concepto, pedido1
)
Select 
    Coalesce(t1.fecha, t2.fecha) as Fecha,
    Coalesce(t1.Sucursal, t2.sDest) as sucursal,
    Coalesce(t1.Operacion, t2.Concepto) as Operacion,
    t1.Monto as MontoTabla1,
    t2.Monto as MontoTaba2

from t1 full join t2 on t1.Fecha = t2.fecha
        and t1.Sucursal = t2.SDest
        and t1.Operacion = t2.Concepto
        And t1.Pedido = t2.Pedido1
Where 
       t1.monto is null and t2.monto is not null 
    or t1.monto is not null and t2.monto is null  
    or t1.monto<> t2.monto ;
```

[image: Res3]

Y si los quieres en una fila agrupados, por fecha, sucursal y Operacion

```
With t1 as(
    Select sum(monto) as monto, fecha, sucursal, Operacion, pedido 
    from tabla_1
    group by fecha, sucursal, Operacion, pedido
), t2 as (
    Select sum(monto) as monto, fecha, SDest, Concepto, pedido1
    from tabla_2
    group by fecha, SDest, Concepto, pedido1
)
Select 
    Coalesce(t1.fecha, t2.fecha) as Fecha,
    Coalesce(t1.Sucursal, t2.sDest) as sucursal,
    Coalesce(t1.Operacion, t2.Concepto) as Operacion,
    sum(t1.Monto) as MontoTabla1,
    sum(t2.Monto) as MontoTaba2

from t1 full join t2 on t1.Fecha = t2.fecha
        and t1.Sucursal = t2.SDest
        and t1.Operacion = t2.Concepto
        And t1.Pedido = t2.Pedido1
Where 
       t1.monto is null and t2.monto is not null 
    or t1.monto is not null and t2.monto is null  
    or t1.monto<> t2.monto 
Group by Coalesce(t1.fecha, t2.fecha),
         Coalesce(t1.Sucursal, t2.sDest),
         Coalesce(t1.Operacion, t2.Concepto);
```

[image: Res4]